# Dubai visa on arrival Indian Passport/UK resident

Tags: indian-citizens, dubai, visas-on-arrival, uk-residents

I am travelling Manchester to Dubai very soon. Emirates website states

"Nationals of India with a normal passport valid for a minimum of 6 months from the arrival date with a residence permit issued by United Kingdom which is valid for a minimum of 6 months can obtain a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 14 days."

I have an Indian passport and Indefinite Leave to Remain UK stamped in my passport.

Is this enough to satisfy Dubai when I arrive?
It's only a small stamp, but has been accepted by UK officials everytime I come back.

Only encountered a problem in Egypt, where they wouldn't accept the stamp (on flight back to UK) but after much explaining they finally accepted it and I was allowed to fly.

So my question is...the indefinite leave stamp I have in my passport, does this meet the criteria "..with a residence permit issued by UK".

2 years ago when I went to Dubai, I applied for a visa online. But at the moment, all visa services have been suspended and their website isn't loading.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you not have a BRP https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits?

Comment: no, I only have ILR stamped in my passport.

found this article which mentions ILR and PR are basically the same thing.

https://immigrationbarrister.co.uk/settled-status-permanent-residence-and-indefinite-leave-to-remain/

"Indefinite leave to remain (ILR)
If you entered the UK before the EEA Regulations 2006 came into force, you may have obtained indefinite leave to remain rather than a right of permanent residence."

Comment: Indeed they are. What did Emirates say when you asked them?

Comment: You can obtain a BRP and it will definitely make your travel easier, as this is what the airlines expect to see. If you've lived in the UK long enough you could also obtain Brtiish citizenship, but this would cause you to lose your Indian citizenship, need to get an OCI, etc.

Comment: When I asked Emirates, they just invited me to use a travel agent to apply for a visa. They didn't really answer my question whether they accept a stamp or not. I am flying in less than a week, and therefore unable to apply for BRP (will definitely get this done soon though!). As I arrived in 1987, I've only got an ILR stamp (maybe that's all that was available during those days), so fingers crossed it works. I normally apply and pay for visa online, but the emirates website is down and says "visa services temporarily suspended"